# I2C freeze on master

Tags: arduino-mega, i2c

On my first big Arduino-project I made a game using the following Arduino's and the I2C-protocol:

- 1x Mega as master
- 4x Mega as slave
- 2x Uno as slave

The Arduino's controll a physical game where the players have to push 96 different buttons, according to how certain lights are controlled by relays. The two uno's are used for a MP3-shield and a timer.

My code might not be perfect at all, but I'm happy with how it works. The only problem is that sometimes my master freezes. This is on different moments, but always when the master processes multiple I2C-communications. Sometimes it completes the whole game without problem, but other times it freezes at different moments.

I used a 1ms delay at the end of the loop on all arduino's, because it looked like this might make the connection most stable. The I2C-cables are up to about 1m long, I can't make them shorter. I added 5K1-resesistors from the 5v-line of the master-Mega on the SDA and SCL line. Alle buttons and relays in the game are connected to seperate power sources and don't use the internal pullups.

The code is quite long, so I uploaded the code of the master and the code of 1 mega slave to Github: https://github.com/mrcbrgrs/Arduino-mega-buttons-game. Some comments might be in Dutch, sorry for that.

Who has an idea how I can stop the Mega from freezing?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Things to try: 1) reduce the pullup resistors, see http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva689/slva689.pdf, 2) reduce the i2c clock frequency, default is 100 khz, see Wire.setclock(), https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireSetClock

Comment: @MikaelPatel 1) I'll try. I already used without external pullup resistors, but was not a difference compared to the the 5K1 setup. 2) I tryed it on the master, but made it freeze very fast every time. Do i have to setclock on all slaves too?

Comment: @chrisl Link to code is in post now, was too long to add in post directly.

Comment: Use 1kΩ pullup resistors. 5k1 is too high even when using short PCB traces.

Comment: I2C is not designed to run over cables without proper "long distance" I2C drivers.

Comment: You askes the same question here: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=628322.0 Is that 6 times 1 meter for a total of 6 meters? That is not possible, the i2c bus can be 50cm long, but that depends on the type of wires or cable. If you can not make them shorter, you might have to drop the i2c bus and think of something else.

Comment: @Majenko Thanks, I will use lower pullup resistors.

Comment: @Jot It's a bit less, think up to 4m in total. But even when I make all the cables shorter, the problems are about the same. So I'm not sure if the length is the problem.

Comment: Try a test with 50cm total length or shorter. If lowering the clock speed does not help, then there might be a ground problem. You need a GND signal that matches SDA and SCL and does not carry high currents of a motor. Only the Master sets the speed of the SCL clock, the Slaves just follow.

Comment: @Jot Thanks again for your help. A short total length had same problem, but also is not an option for the end product. The GND is directly from master-arduino (9v adapter). The master arduino does not power any elements. The clock speed change on the master only resulted on a crash almost every time the master needed to communicate, while without changes it only happens once in a while.

Comment: That is a serious problem. I have had multiple arduino slaves with a mega as a master without any problems. The pullup is 5 * 10k and 7 * 30k and 5k1, that is almost as low as 1k, that is too low. Without your 5k1 there is still too much pullup. At least remove the 5k1 resistors. On the arduino.cc forum they wrote about removing the Serial.println from the interrupt functions. Did you do that?

Comment: @Jot The setup is in a different workplace, so I'm collecting all info before driving there. Will try the tips soon and let know. Will also get some PCA9615 as I2C bus extenders to use as alternative.